# How to configure ssl for data in transit when using akka persistence with mysql and dnvriend (dnvriend / akka-persistence-jdbc)

Tags: mysql, akka-persistence

I want to enable encryption of data in transit for akka FSM. I am using dnvriend / akka-persistence-jdbc with Mysql. What are the steps involved in enabling ssl for db connections? How do I verify that the data is encrypted? If I use the url parameter useSSL=true, does the connection automatically fallback to non ssl if MySql server doesn't support ssl?

I tried to toggle the switch useSSL in the JDBC url and didn't observe any changes or didn't get any errors.

Comment: Intercept the data between the client and the server. Can you read the textual data?

Comment: update: When connecting to a mysql server with ssl enabled using the plugin(dnvriend / akka-persistence-jdbc ), connection is not established. But do not see any errors/info in the logs to suggest what is going wrong. connecting string has "verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true" as additional parameters.